# Initializing Jagged Array in Julia

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia. I am trying to initialize a jagged array of known size K in the first dimension, and unknown size in the second dimension.

The way I currently do this is

```
arr = Array{Array{Int}}(undef, K)
for i in 1:K
    arr[i] = []
end
# and then push! elements to arr[k] if the element is in category k.
```

Can we do this in a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest to write is I think:

```
arr = [Int[] for _ in 1:K]
```

You could also write (I am showing these as an exercise as I would normally use a comprehension):

```
arr = map(_ -> Int[], 1:K)
```

or

```
arr = (_ -> Int[]).(1:K)
```

A common mistake that should be avoided is:

```
arr = fill(Int[], K)
```

as then each element of `arr` is exactly the same vector, which you do not want. E.g.

```
julia> arr = fill(Int[], K)
5-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 []
 []
 []
 []
 []

julia> push!(arr[1], 1)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> arr
5-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
```